# Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys errorno 150

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

My insert statements are:

```
create table department (
    name varchar (30) primary key
);
create table PIO (id varchar (5), name varchar (30), dept_name varchar (30), email_id varchar (30),
    primary key ( id, name),
    foreign key(dept_name) references department (name) on delete cascade);

create table applicant (
   name varchar(30), email_id varchar (30), phone varchar (15), address text
    );
create table application (app_name varchar (30), app_id int, pio_id varchar (5), pio_name varchar (30), dat DATE,content text,
    primary key (app_name,app_id,pio_id,pio_name),
    foreign key (app_name) references applicant (name),
    foreign key (pio_id) references  PIO (id),
    foreign key (pio_name) references PIO (name)
    );
```

The last(application) table doesn't get created....it gives the following error:

> Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys errorno 150

Answer (score 1):

PIO (id) and (name) are not keys, so you cannot declare foreign keys to them in application.
You probably mean instead of those two FKs to have one:

```
--in application
foreign key (pio_id,pio_name) references PIO (id,name)
```

This forces every particular (pio_id,pio_name) pair in PIO to appear as an (id,name) pair in application.

It is *possible* that you just want (pio_id)s to appear as (id)s and (io_name)s to appear as (name)s. That is two "inclusion dependency" (IND) constraints. A FK constraint is an IND constraint referencing a PK or UNIQUE subrow. It is hard to code a non-FK IND constraint in SQL.